# ng-model value not passed to the controller function

Tags: angularjs, forms, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

I am using ng-model to pass the form value to a controller function. But it is not passing correct values of the check boxes. Here is my plunker. Please help me out with this.

https://plnkr.co/edit/3gOuQwzt3SMNbAXplq0x?p=preview

My template is:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade " ng-repeat="(key, value) in all_user_wl_data" id="{{key}}" ng-class='{"in active":$first}'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" ng-repeat="(key1, value1)  in value.wl_dict">
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                <input id="{{key1}}" type="checkbox" name="valueis" class="form-control" ng-model="formData[key1]">
                                    <label for="{{key1}}">
                                        {{value1}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"> <label class="control-label">Group Name </label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"> <input type="text" name="regular" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.key2"></div></div><br>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="" title="" ng-click="createGroup(formData)">Save changes</button>

                </div>
```

Here when I print console.log(formData), it prints only the value of text box and doesn't prints checkbox value.

Comment: try define  $scope.formData = []; in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. in controller define  `$scope.formData = [];`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initiate $scope for checkbox ng-model "`formData`" ..

So if you initiate model into controller like this ,  `$scope.formData = []`

It will append true value in your `formData` like this,

```
[2221: true, 8233: true]
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone suggested.
Set $scope.formData in controller

Working plnkr

use

```
$scope.formData = {}
```

in your controller

https://plnkr.co/edit/53YVnVyOQzqxHQIPshkq?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I changed your script to below and it works

```
angular.module('formExample', [])   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
                $scope.formData = {};
                $http.get('test.json')
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.all_user_wl_data = data;
                        angular.forEach(data, function(areadata) {
                            $scope.usersubscribedwl = data;
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                    })

                $scope.createGroup = function() {
                    console.log($scope.formData);
                }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input id="{{key1}}" type="checkbox" name="valueis" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.key1[value1]">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.formData=[];
```

[https://plnkr.co/](https://plnkr.co/edit/cWo6bBCCilD6R3GN7ZBF?p=preview)